# difference between rows with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

this is my dataframe sample.

[image]

I want to add a column which give difference between previous period by GL.
My result should be:

[image]

thanks

Comment: Could you please also post the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["diff"]=df.groupby("GL")["value"].diff().fillna(df["value"])
```

Outputs for the sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"a": list("xyzyyzvx"), "b": [4.6, 33.2, -5, 2.34,1,9,-6.89,23]})

df["diff"]=df.groupby("a")["b"].diff().fillna(df["b"])

>>> df

   a      b   diff
0  x   4.60   4.60
1  y  33.20  33.20
2  z  -5.00  -5.00
3  y   2.34 -30.86
4  y   1.00  -1.34
5  z   9.00  14.00
6  v  -6.89  -6.89
7  x  23.00  18.40
```

Comment: Hi Grezgorz. I have an error : TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Could you post your exact code - you did like: ```df["diff"]=df.groupby("GL")["value"].diff().fillna(df["value"])```, right? If so - try maybe upgrading ```pandas```

Comment: Just another question, could I group with more than one column. as I need to have Class also..?

Comment: find...just add in groupby ['GL','class']